# Add BoxViews dynamically

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have an `ObservableCollection` of objects that gets stored in the `ViewModel` and for each object I want to add a `BoxView` to my `View`.  I cannot figure how to make this happen dynamically however.  I am using the code below but the OnBindingContextChanged() doesn't get called until after the page is drawn.

How can I draw `BoxViews` for each member in my collection and have it display?

```
public partial class MyPage
{
    private MyViewModel _viewModel;

    public MyPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnBindingContextChanged()
    {
        base.OnBindingContextChanged();
        _viewModel = BindingContext as MyViewModel;
        var collection = _viewModel.MyCollection;

        foreach (var item in cargoList)
        {
            BuildCargoItem(item.Width, item.Height, item.Position);
        }
    }

    public void BuildCargoItem(int width = 150, int height = 150, int position = 0)
    {
        BoxView boxView = new BoxView
        {
            Color = Color.Blue,
            WidthRequest = width,
            HeightRequest = height,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand
        };

        grid.Children.Add(boxView, 450, position);
    }
}
```

Comment: when adding an item to a Grid, the coordinates mean col, row - you have 450 cols in your grid?

Comment: Wow, I'm in disbelief!  You are a lifesaver, I was pulling my hair out!   Intellisense said the properties were (View view, int left, int top) so I thought it was positioning, not rows and columns.  Thank you so much!

Comment: I guess it's a mistake on IntelliSense Grid's documentation. I've noticed it too.